# Properly setting Extents in Arcpy Using path

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, extents

I am trying to set the extents of my processing using Arcpy, but when my processing is completed, there has been no change to the extents (it results in an extent that did not go as large as I desire).

Included is the code I have been using for the extents:

```
arcpy.env.extent = 'C:\data\myData.tif'
```

What I am using as an input would bea .tif file, so I am not sure if that would matter or not.

After using this, I am attempting a Euclidean Distance analysis, where I have:

```
arcpy.gp.EucDistance_sa(input, euclidean_output, "", "200", Output_direction_raster)
```

As I said earlier, it just returns the same output without the extent change. Would anyone be able to give me some tips?

Comment: Perhaps in this instance the mask http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000001t000000 setting might be more appropriate. If the extent doesn't have a well defined spatial reference that can cause issues (defaulting to 'everything'). If you read the docs on extent http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/ it can be an *extent*, min/max of or a dataset that has an extent, you can specify your extent as an object if that helps http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000006r000000

Comment: The issue with making the extent an object is that it is a raster, which I was led to believe would not work if you were to say, make it a cursor object to get the extents.

Comment: arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Describe(InRaster).extent, this will get the overall extent of any raster or feature class and use that for the extent... however that's theoretically what arcpy.env.extent = InRaster should do. You can break that down by getting the extent object and printing that to the output to see that the extent is being set properly.

Answer (score -1):

The actual issue was my naming conventions. My .tif file was long and began with a number. I should have realized this earlier. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer because the only *.tif that you showed us was `'C:\data\myData.tif'`, and in any event I think that path would also have caused problems when it encountered single backslashes.  I suspect that using `arcpy.env.extent = r'C:\data\myData.tif'` would have been much more likely to work as expected.  It is important to always provide code snippets that work up to where you are stuck when you post questions.